# How to know that the operator is being pressed?

Tags: python, scripting

I have created a function above in the script, I want the function repeated if I press the *Continue* button.

To do this, I would need to tell `bpy` that this operator is `True` or `pressed` but I don't know how to do that.

[image]

code is here.

````
import bpy
import bpy.utils.previews
from easybpy import *
from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty, IntProperty, EnumProperty, FloatProperty
from bpy.types import PropertyGroup, Operator, Panel
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper, ExportHelper


def datafunc(boxes, upload):
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    props = scene.COMP_PROPS
    boxes.label(text='Country Name')
    boxes.use_property_split = True
    boxes.use_property_decorate = False
    boxes.prop(props, 'String')
    boxes.prop(props, 'Float')
    img = boxes.operator(upload)
            
class ComparisionProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    Float : FloatProperty(name='')
    String : StringProperty(name='')

class ImageOpertoar(Operator, ImportHelper):
    bl_label = 'Upload Image'
    bl_idname = "upload.image"
    
    filter_glob: StringProperty(
    default='*.BMP;*.JPG;*.IRIS;*.PNG;*.JPEG;*.TARGA;*.OPENEXR;*.TIFF;*.WebP;*.GIF;',
    options={'HIDDEN'})
    
    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.image.open(filepath=self.filepath, use_udim_detecting=False)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class ComparisionPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = 'Compare'
    bl_idname = 'COMPARE_DATA'
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_context = ''
    bl_category = 'Comparision'
    bl_order = 0
    bl_ui_units_x=0

    def draw_header(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row() 
        row.label(text='Enter your Data', icon_value=0)    
        
        boxes = layout.box()
        upload = 'upload.image'
        datafunc(boxes, upload)
        
        row1 = layout.row()
        row1.operator('continue.panel')
        datafunc(boxes, upload)    
        row1.operator('finish.panel')        
        
class ComparisionContinue(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = 'Continue'
    bl_idname = 'continue.panel'
    
    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
class ComparisionFinish(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = 'Finish'
    bl_idname = 'finish.panel'
    
    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ComparisionProperties)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ComparisionPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ImageOpertoar)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ComparisionContinue)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ComparisionFinish)
    bpy.types.Scene.COMP_PROPS = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=ComparisionProperties)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ComparisionProperties)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ComparisionPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ImageOpertoar)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ComparisionContinue)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ComparisionFinish)
    del bpy.types.Scene.COMP_PROPS
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````

Comment: Using global variables

Comment: what do you mean? How would I do this? any example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a similar example you can refer to

[image]

```
import bpy

my_data = []

class PropGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    my_string : bpy.props.StringProperty(name='')

class Op_add(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.op_add"
    bl_label = "Add text"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        my_data.append(bpy.context.scene.my_group.my_string)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class Op_fin(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.op_fin"
    bl_label = "Get result"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        print("Op_fin execute")
        return {'FINISHED'}
    def invoke(self,context,event):
        self.s = '-'.join(my_data)
        my_data.clear()
        return context.window_manager.invoke_popup(self)

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.column().label(text=f"Result = {self.s}")

class XX_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "XX_PT_Panel"
    bl_label = "XX Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "NEW"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.row().prop(bpy.context.scene.my_group, "my_string")
        layout.row().operator("wm.op_add", text = f"Add text {len(my_data) if my_data else ''}")
        if my_data:
            layout.row().operator("wm.op_fin")


def register():
    g = globals()
    for k in g:
        if isinstance(g[k], type): # Check if it is a class
            bpy.utils.register_class(g[k])

    bpy.types.Scene.my_group = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=PropGroup)

def unregister(): pass
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for writing the script for me. I am new to bpy, that's why I was not getting you.